# Jumps (#name) is not working on .asp file

Tags: html

Page name is experts.asp. I want to use a jump to go though a long list of people and have the h1 element of their name at the top of the window. I've tested jumps and they work fine on HTML pages not on my asp page. Please help me to do this..

My code is here..

```
<ul class="experts">
    <li><a href="#sami">Sami</a></li>
    <li><a href="#michael">Michael</a></li>
    <li><a href="#greg">Greg</a></li>
    <li><a href="#david">David</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tom">Tom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#gaston">Gaston</a></li>
    <li><a href="#matt">Matt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#dennis">Dennis</a></li>
    <li><a href="#michelle">Michelle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#maria">Maria</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#greg">Greg</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And here is one of the sections I want jumped to:

```
<h1 name="michael">Michael</h1> <img src="..." alt="Michael " class="expert">
 <p></p>
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of the rendered html file? The parser is probably changing the # symbol.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `id` attribute instead of `name`.

```
<h1 id="michael">Michael</h1> <img src="..." alt="Michael " class="expert">
 <p></p>
```